# High order function with javascript trouble

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I want to be able to run the func n times with this createIterator function.

```
var createIterator = function (func, n) {
  getDouble = function (x) {
    return x + x;
  };

  return getDouble * n;
};
```

I want to be able to do this with the code:

```
var getQuad = createIterator(getDouble, 2);
getQuad(2) //8
```

Here are the tests is needs to pass:

```
Test.describe("Iterator for 'getDouble' function", function() {
  var getDouble = function (n) {
  return n + n;
  };

  Test.it("Running the iterator for once", function() {
    var doubleIterator = createIterator(getDouble, 1);

    Test.assertEquals(doubleIterator(3), 6, "Returns double of 3 as 6");
    Test.assertEquals(doubleIterator(5), 10, "Returns double of 5 as 10");
  });

  Test.it("Running the iterator twice", function() {
    var getQuadruple = createIterator(getDouble, 2);

    Test.assertEquals(getQuadruple(2), 8, "Returns quadruple of 2 as 8");
    Test.assertEquals(getQuadruple(5), 20, "Returns quadruple of 5 as 20");
   });
});
```

I have been at this for awhile and have not been able to figure this out. Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Do you just want to run the `getDouble` a certain amount of times, `n`. Does the parameter stay the same?

Comment: yes I just want to run getDouble n times. getQuad(5) would return 20. I am not sure if I am answering your question.

Comment: _"yes I just want to run getDouble n times. getQuad(5) would return 20."_ How would `20` be returned from `getQuad(5)` ?

Comment: it would run 5 + 5 from the getDouble function and then run that function 2 times making it equal 20. The idea behind the createIterator function is that it would execute *func*, *n* times on a supplied input. I am not great at this haha but I hope that explains it better. The code inside the createIterator function is not right but the function params are what they need to be.

Comment: @JuniorSauce Note, `getDouble` would be `undefined` at `var getQuad = createIterator(getDouble, 2);`. See post

Comment: You are right. I just added the tests it needs to pass. The way I currently have `getDouble` it is function scoped inside the `createIterator` function. The code inside that function is probably not right and `getDouble` could be declared outside the `createIterator` function. Thanks for you help so far by the way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a simple `repeat` procedure that when applied to `n`, `f`, and `x`, will *repeat* the application of function ***f*** to argument ***x***, ***n*** times.

```
// ES6
const repeat = n => f => x =>
  n === 1 ? f(x) : repeat(n-1)(f)(f(x));

const getDouble = x => x * 2;

const double = repeat(1)(getDouble);
const quad = repeat(2)(getDouble);
```

See it work

```
console.log(double(3)); // 6
console.log(double(5)); // 10
console.log(quad(2));   // 8
console.log(quad(5));   // 20
```

---

Let step through the evaluation of one of the examples:

```
const double = repeat(1)(getDouble);
```

Because `repeat` has been applied to `n` and `f` here, it returns

```
x => 1 === 1 ? getDouble(x) : repeat(0)(getDouble)(getDouble(x))
```

Now, when we call

```
double(3);
```

Substitute `3` for `x`

```
1 === 1 ? getDouble(3) : repeat(0)(getDouble)(getDouble(3));
```

Because `1 === 1`, the first part of the ternary expression is returned

```
getDouble(3); // 6
```

Recap:

```
double(3) === getDouble(3) === 6
```

---

Now let's see the same process for `quad`

```
const quad = repeat(2)(getDouble);
```

Because `repeat` has been applied to `n` and `f` here, it returns

```
x => 2 === 1 ? getDouble(x) : repeat(1)(getDouble)(getDouble(x))
```

Now, when we call

```
quad(2);
```

Substitue `2` for `x`

```
2 === 1 ? getDouble(2) : repeat(1)(getDouble)(getDouble(2));
```

Because `2 === 1` is false, the second part of the ternary expression is returned

```
repeat(1)(getDouble)(getDouble(2))
repeat(1)(getDouble)(4)
```

So we have to call `repeat` again, with `n=1`, `f=getDouble`, `x=4`, so

```
1 === 1 ? getDouble(4) : repeat(0)(getDouble)(getDouble(4))
```

Because `1 === 1`, the first part of the ternary expression is returned

```
getDouble(4); // 8
```

Recap:

```
quad(2) === getDouble(4) ===  8
```

---

If you need the **ES5**, here you go

```
// ES5
var repeat = function repeat(n) {
  return function (f) {
    return function (x) {
      return n === 1 ? f(x) : repeat(n - 1)(f)(f(x));
    };
  };
};

var getDouble = function getDouble(x) {
  return x * 2;
};

var double = repeat(1)(getDouble);
var quad = repeat(2)(getDouble);

console.log(double(3)); // 6
console.log(double(5)); // 10
console.log(quad(2));   // 8
console.log(quad(5));   // 20
```

---

Lastly,

If you want your original API, which I believe to be inferior, we can still implement that

```
// ES6
const createIterator = (f, n) => x =>
  n === 1 ? f(x) : createIterator(f, n-1)(f(x));

const getDouble = x => x * 2;

const double = createIterator(getDouble, 1);
const quad = createIterator(getDouble, 2);
```

And here's the **ES5**

```
// ES5
var createIterator = function createIterator(f, n) {
  return function (x) {
    return n === 1 ? f(x) : createIterator(f, n - 1)(f(x));
  };
};

var getDouble = function getDouble(x) {
  return x * 2;
};

var double = createIterator(getDouble, 1);
var quad = createIterator(getDouble, 2);
```

Both implementations work identically

---

So why is `repeat(n)(f)(x)` better ?

Well, because the function is fully curried, you can partially apply it in meaningful ways.

```
const getDouble = x => x * 2;

const once = repeat(1);
const twice = repeat(2);
const thrice = repeat(3);

const quad = twice(getDouble);
quad(5); // 20

const annoyingAlert = thrice(x => {alert(x); return x;});
annoyingAlert('wake up !'); // displays 'wake up !' three times
```

Your function isn't as flexible because it takes the function, `f`, and the number of times, `n`, as a tuple. Getting around this would require manually currying your function or using a `Function.prototype.bind` hack.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for detailed response and alternate solutions! I just got schooled haha.

Comment: `repeat(n-1)(f)(f(x))` is function composition. So we can deduce a point-free version: `const comp = f => g => x => f(g(x))` and `const repeat = n => f => n > 1 ? comp(f)(repeat(n-1)(f)) : f`. However, this version is not better, only an alternative.

Comment: @IvenMarquardt nice catch. Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score -1):

Try rearranging variables. Note, `getDouble` would be `undefined` at `var getQuad = createIterator(getDouble, 2);` as `getDouble` is defined within `createIterator`

```js
var createIterator = function (func, n) {
  getDouble = function (x) {
    return (x + x) * n;
  };

  return func || getDouble;
};

var getQuad = createIterator(null, 2);
console.log(getQuad(2)) //8
```

alternatively

```js
var createIterator = function(func, n) {
  getDouble = function(x) {
    return x + x;
  };

  return func.bind(null, n * n) || (getDouble(n)) * n;
};

var getQuad = createIterator(function(x) {
  return x + x;
}, 2);

console.log(getQuad(2))
```

> I just want to run getDouble n times.

You could use a loop inside of `createIterator` , return accumulated value  as variable within function returned from `createIterator` that can be multiplied by parameter passed to `getQuad`

```js
var createIterator = function(func, n) {

  getDouble = function(x) {
    return x + x;
  };

  var curr = n, res = 0;
  while (--curr) {
    res += func && func(n) || getDouble(n);
  }

  return function(y) {
    return res * y
  }

};

var getQuad = createIterator(null, 2);
console.log(getQuad(5)) // 20
```

Comment: This works perfect for the getQuad function but I need to some how make this work for something like this as well:
    var double = createIterator(getDouble, 1);
    double(3) //6
    double(5) //10

Sorry I did not clarify that earlier. This is the last requirement.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this,

1. Create an empty array of `n`
2. Fill the array by the function(arguments)
3. Join the array by operator
4. Create a function constructor using the joined array and arguments
5. Use the new function inside another function to pass the arguments from outside, and then return this new function.

Code snippet of what I am saying is here (if your browser supports Array.prototype.fill)

```js
var createIterator = function (func, n, operator) {
  operator = operator || "+";
  var inner = Function(["f", "a"], "return " + Array(n ).fill("f(a)").join(operator) + ";");
  return function (arg) {
    return inner(func, arg);    
  };
};


var c = createIterator(function (n) {return n + n;}, 2);

document.write(c(3) + "<br/>");

document.write(c(6) + "<br/>");


var d = createIterator(function (n) {return n + n;}, 3, "+");

document.write(d(3) + "<br/>");

document.write(d(6) + "<br/>");
```

otherwise use this snippet

```js
var createIterator = function (func, n, operator) {
  operator = operator || "+";
  var array = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {array[i] = "f(a)";}
  var inner = Function(["f", "a"], "return " + array.join(operator) + ";");
  return function (arg) {
    return inner(func, arg);    
  };
};


var c = createIterator(function (n) {return n + n;}, 2);

document.write(c(3) + "<br/>");

document.write(c(6) + "<br/>");


var d = createIterator(function (n) {return n + n;}, 3, "+");

document.write(d(3) + "<br/>");

document.write(d(6) + "<br/>");
```

Comment: This code seems work its not passing my tests. I get an `Object has no method 'fill'` error. This is a more complicated problem then I thought. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I see the [].fill method may not be supported by your browser, so instead use for loop, i have updated my answer, check it.